# What is the best way to get all form inputs data with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

suppose i have a form with id and all the input,checkbox,radio etc fields.

What is the best way to retrieve all the values?  I mean putting an id to all the fields or serialize the `form` in `javascript/jquery`?

Code is very common.

```
<head>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<form id="f1">

    <input type="text" name="firstname">
    <br>
    Last name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
    <br><br>
<input type="button" id="b1"value="Submit">
<input type="checkbox" name="cb[]" value="1"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="cb[]" value="2"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="cb[]" value="3"/>
</form>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#b1").click(function(){
    //console.log($("#f1").serializeArray());    

    var requestObj = {};
var formObj = $(this).closest("form");
$.each($(formObj).serializeArray(), function (index, value) {
    requestObj[value.name] = value.value;
});
console.log(requestObj);
    })

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the successful inputs' values simply by doing this:

```
var stringData = $('#form-id').serialize();
```

This will create a query string that's meant to be sent with an HTTP request

Instead, if you want the values stored in an array you can do:

```
var arrayData = $('#form-id').serializeArray();
```

Comment: but suppose for example,I have two textfield, one radio button, 2 check boxes and all are mandatory. User selects only textfield and radio button not the checkbox then how to confirm its not selected? as checkbox key wont come.

Comment: @Robun : for checkboxes id they aren't serialized, it means they aren't checked by the user

Comment: ya that means I have to check for the checkbox name whether it is there or not in string and show the message? I thought other solutions would be there! thanks for confirmation Moppo!

Comment: @Robun : If you use the string in an HTTP request, and the checkbox name doesn't come as a parameter it means it's unchecked, otherwise it's checked. But there is no need to check the 'string' as it should come as a parameter to the request you sent. Or, if you don't send the request, you can use `serializeArray` and check if the array has the element with the checkbox name

Answer (score 1):

*I mean putting id to all fields of serialize the form in javascript/jquery?*

No, not IDs but `name` attribute should have to be there as this is required for all inputs to serialize.

and you can use two methods of your choice:

```
var frmData = $('#formId').serialize(); // produces queryString '?name=value&name=value'
var frmData = $('#formId').serializeArray(); // produces array [{name:name, value:value}]
```

Comment: At least you could have used a different string for  `#form-id` :)

Comment: but if want checkbox also but user dont pick it then how to validate it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some new,This is directly map your fields name with model

```
var requestObj = {};
var formObj = $($this).closest("form");
$.each($(formObj).serializeArray(), function (index, value) {
    requestObj[value.name] = value.value;
});
```

and in ajax part

```
data: JSON.stringify({ objectName: requestObj }),
```